# JMeter proxy & flex/flash

Tags: flash, apache-flex, proxy, jmeter

I'm trying to use JMeter to test our web application and I'd like to use an automated recording of tests but our UI is in flash/flex.  Is there any way to get the proxy server to cooperate with the flash/flex?  I do have control of both the client and server sides, though rewriting our application to redirect  the flash/flex calls to another address isn't really an option.  If there were an automated way...

I'm currently testing Windows client and server, but I also need to support testing on Linux client and server.  If tests need to be created on one or the other and can be ported to both I could live with that.

Comment: you use it in windows, linux, mac?

Comment: @revo: Windows or Linux.  Added info to description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a solution to this may be to use a reverse proxy such as Charles.  I haven't tried it yet, but found a post about doing this here: http://www.sujitnayak.com/?cat=9

I'm answering my own question, but please comment or post another answer if you have more information/experience or an alternative solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11683200/460802